# cannot install pakages in Ubuntu 17.04

Tags: apt, package-management, dpkg

I tried to install pakage such as `net-tools` but all i get is this error:

```
After this operation, 745 kB of additional disk space will be used.
dpkg: error processing package util-linux (--configure):
 package util-linux is not ready for configuration
 cannot configure (current status 'half-installed')
Errors were encountered while processing:
 util-linux
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Answer (score 0):

It's been a long time since this happened to me but I believe you need to resolve that half installed package by doing

```
sudo dpkg --configure -a
sudo apt-get update
```

This will try install the cached package. (util-linux)

Comment: well after ran the command above the result is :                                                                                                                     `dpkg: dependency problems prevent processing triggers for systemd:
 systemd depends on util-linux (>= 2.27.1); however:
  Package util-linux is not installed.

dpkg: error processing package systemd (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving triggers unprocessed
Errors were encountered while processing:
 systemd
`

Comment: Are you not able to do `sudo apt-get install util-linux` ?

Comment: yes, i ran it the result is the same error above!